# starting range() as len(<some_list>) VS starting range() as len(<some_list>)-1 [Inclusive/Exclusive end]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I can't seem to understand when does the end condition is included and when it's not depending of the start as a length of list or length of list deducted by one (last position) , without modifying the end with the step value

I wanted to pop elements from a list within a loop
(Note: I know that setting `range(0,len(colors_list))` like this will do the  trick too)

```
colors_list = ["green","blue","yellow","pink","violet","black"]
```

I tried this snippet of code, and the end was included :-

```
for color in range(len(colors_list),0,-1):
    colors_list.pop()

print(colors_list)
```

```
Output : []
```

and I tried this too, but here the end was excluded :-

```
for color in range(len(colors_list)-1,0,-1):
    colors_list.pop() 

print(colors_list)
```

```
Output : ["green"]
```

I understand the second trial as the 0th index is not popped, but the first trial is what I dont understand, like isn't it supposed to be the same as the second ? considering that it stop befrore the 0th index ? but the first element is popped instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end was excluded in both cases. You ran the loop one fewer times in the second case, because you added the `-1` to the start condition. The end value is *always* exclusive, the start value is *always* inclusive.

Just listify and `print` the `range`s and you'll see:

```
>>> colors_list = ["green","blue","yellow","pink","violet","black"]
>>> print(list(range(len(colors_list),0,-1)))
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

>>> print(list(range(len(colors_list)-1,0,-1)))
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

No `0` on either, you just began the loop from `6` on one, and `5` on the other.